# Cannot remove part of $PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I trying to fix any problem I have in `brew doctor`, so I see:

```
Warning: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    /usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/
```

I look into `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/paths` – and don't see this path.

There is no files in `/etc/paths.d/` folder that contains this string.

So where this `$PATH` part from?

Comment: Have you tried `echo $PATH` in your terminal?

Comment: The $PATH can also be modified by launch agents/daemons and any shell script in your *profile files!

Comment: @user556068 tried. How it can help me?

Comment: @klanomath okay, how can I find them?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't see a directory ending in a `/` when you run `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds like the problem is a directory ending in a `/`. And it sounds like Homebrew is telling you the directory causing the error is `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/`. If this is the case then you simply need to remove the trailing `/` from this directory.

But it also sounds like you are saying you don't see this problem directory in your `$PATH`. Running `echo $PATH` will show you which directories are in your PATH. If your PATH contains a lot of directories as mine does, this can be a little hard to read. So maybe you are just overlooking it?

In any case, here is a simple script to show you all the directories in your PATH; 1 per line.

```
#!/bin/bash

# save IFS to a variable    
old_IFS=${IFS$' \t\n'}

#set IFS to a colon
IFS=':'

for item in ${PATH[@]}
do 
    echo $item
done

# set IFS back to the default setting
IFS=$old_IFS
```

Or if you prefer copy and paste directly in your terminal:

```
old_IFS=${IFS-$' \t\n'}; IFS=':'; for item in ${PATH[@]}; do echo $item; done; IFS=$old_IFS
```

Or an even simpler way as pointed out by fd0 in the comments:

```
tr -s ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH"
```

This also has the added advantage of not needing to mess around with `IFS`.

Using any of the above scripts, if you find a line ending in a `/` then you've found the culprit.

Comment: Your code could be simplified using `tr` with a `herestring`- `tr -s ':' '\n' <<<"$PATH"`

Comment: @fd0 Thanks for the info. I updated the answer with your simplified method.

Comment: No I see this problem part of PATH if I run `echo $PATH`. The output will be `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/ /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /opt/X11/bin /usr/local/sbin /Users/grawl/.composer/vendor/bin`.

Comment: Then you need to remove the trailing `/` from `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/`

Comment: @user556068 obviously. But I cannot find a file to edit.

Comment: I'm confused.. or you are. `/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin` is a directory not a file.